# Дать значение json array

Tags: java, json

Имею json

```
{"account", "fullnickname" : "lol"}
```

Мне нужно для поля fullnickname дать значение
Делаю так:

```
        try {
            String data = "{"account", "fullnickname" : "lol"}";
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            jsonObject.getJSONArray("account").put("fullnickname", "trcxp");
        }catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Но у меня не получается(

Comment: это не валидный json

Comment: JSON объект должен быть как минимум {"account":null, "fullnickname" : "lol"}

Answer (score 0):

У вас невалидный JSON. Предположу, что у вас должен быть `account` со значениями:

```
{
 "account" : { 
  "fullnickname" : "lol",
  //другие поля, например
  "password" : "34mgrkedosflr"
  }
}
```

Тогда вам нужно сделать так:

```
try {
    String data = "{ "account" : { "fullnickname" : "lol", "password" : "34mgrkedosflr" } }";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
    jsonObject.getJSONObject("account").put("fullnickname", "trcxp");
}catch (Exception e) { }
```